# Neo4j: Testing PageRank 'None' results

Tags: neo4j, pagerank

I'm testing *PageRank* in a projected graph **'ns_reverse'** where I've applied before *Node Similarity*. My dataset has initially two types of nodes 'Keywords' and 'Articles' that are linked by a relationship 'APPEARS_IN', like this:

**Keyword-[APPEARS_IN]->Article**

After applying *Node Similarity*, my projected graph has also a new relationship 'SIMILAR', like this:

**Article-[SIMILAR]->Article**

Now that I'm testing *PageRank* to mesure the importance of each 'Article' node, I getting 'None' for the nodes type 'Keyword' but I do not want 'Keywords' nodes to be mesured. Here is the code:

```
CALL gds.pageRank.stream('ns_reverse') 
YIELD nodeId, score 
RETURN gds.util.asNode(nodeId).title AS title,
       gds.util.asNode(nodeId).keyword AS keyword, score
ORDER BY score DESC, title ASC
```

I returned both, nodes title and nodes keywords to show you the 'None' results in both columns:
[image: Results]

I only want to mesure the importance of 'Articles' nodes. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want PR to be computed only for `Article` nodes, you need to create another projected graph containing only these nodes and the relationship between them (I guess it is the new `SIMILAR` relationship):

```
CALL gds.graph.create("pgraph_article", "Article", "SIMILAR")
```

and then use this new projected graph when computing PR:

```
CALL gds.pageRank.stream("pgraph_article", {})
YIELD nodeId, score 
RETURN gds.util.asNode(nodeId).title AS title, score
ORDER BY score DESC, title ASC
```